# How to add a digital clock to Latte Dock?

Tags: latte-dock

I am running 20.04 LTS with Gnome 3.36.8 on X11 and just installed Latte Dock.

Is it possible to replace the analog clock with a digital clock ?
I tried to click on "Add widgets..." menu item but nothing happens.
Am I missing something that needs to be installed ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need kde plasma for this

Comment: Log into kde desktop then right click anywhere and click add widgets  , click get new widgets, search the desired widgets and download it. Then right click on latte dock and select add widgets, select and drop the widget you want to latte dock then log back to gnome and your ptoblem is fixed :)

Comment: The OP says he has the dock installed and is not running kde plasma so both your comments seem to be off topic. Unless the OP changes or adds some missing info to say he is.

Comment: OK, thks, so I guess I have to install kde plasma.. thx